# How to write custom method in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I write this method in RoR?

```
if item is nil or item.user!='my_value' redirect_to "/"
```

Want to call it like so:

```
@item = Item.find(params[:id])
method_described_earlier(@item)
```

Or other way.
Want to see how rails pro would do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a [before_filter](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#other-ways-to-use-filters), which will run before any set of controller actions you indicate. For example:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :require_special_item, only: [:myaction, :other_action, ...]

  def myaction
    # do something with @item
  end

  private

    def require_special_item
      @item = Item.find(params[:id])
      if @item is nil or @item.user!='my_value'
        redirect_to "/"
      end
    end
end
```

The method `require_special_item` will always run before `myaction` and any other actions you indicate, redirecting the user if the found item doesn't meet your requirements.

Comment: it sounds like it will make two queries - one is for before_filter, and one - for myaction. is it ok?

Comment: No, once you query for the item in the `before_filter` and save the result in the instance variable `@item`, this variable will be available to your controller action, assuming the filter did not call `redirect_to`.

Comment: Ok, so should I comment out the line Item.find in all actions listed under before_filter? Or it doesn't matter?

Comment: Yes, you should. It will work either way, but there is no need to run the same queries twice.